# How to create a nav-bar in bootstrap 4 with hyper links

Tags: bootstrap-4

Please share a code snippet of the working navbar. I tried doing via w3schools but was no help. any helps would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">nav</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Check this, hope this will help you.

Comment: Anytime @VenkateshaNagaraj